# matlab Error using feval

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a code for creating spectogram from .wav file in matlab. The code is as follows:

```
 [song, fs] = wavread('combofile.wav');
 left = song(:,1);
 figure;
 spectrogram(left);
```

Code must plot spectogram.

But I am getting an error as

> Error using feval
>   Undefined function 'radiobutton16_Callback' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
>           feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in untitled (line 50) gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in @(hObject,eventdata) untitled('radiobutton16_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Ho can I fix this? the error occurs when I click on a radio button.

Comment: The most likely reason for the error is that you deleted or renamed the function `radiobutton16_Callback` in the file `untitled.m`. The radio button you clicked has the tag `radiobutton16`, an identifier automatically created by `guide`. `guide` also generated a callback template called `radiobutton16_Callback` in the file `untitled.m`, i.e. a function that is executed when you click the button.  BTW, you should not call your function `untitled` ...

Comment: @souty saved my day. thanks.